# Python - can't find file specified & permission denied on file operation

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Hi I am checking to see if a excel file is modified, and if it is basically save it as something else and open it.  So it works the first time around, but on the second time I modify the file, I am getting error: The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\example.xlsx'

Sometimes it would also throw: Permission denied: 'C:\Todolist2.xlsx'

Please help.  Newbie here.  Thank You

```
import time, os.path, os, openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

currentFD = os.stat("C:\\example.xlsx")

while True:

    modDate = os.stat("C:\\example.xlsx")

    if (modDate > currentFD):
        print('yes it does')
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\example.xlsx")
        wb.save("C:\\Todolist2.xlsx")
        os.startfile("C:\\Todolist2.xlsx")

        currentFD = modDate
```

Comment: Please give us the traceback, not just a description of the error. Without knowing which line the error came from, it's pretty hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: Meanwhile, does `C:\example.xlsx` actually exist? Do you have permissions to create new files in `C:\`? Or, if `C:\Todolist2.xlsx` already exists, do you have permissions to overwrite it, and do you know that it's not opened with an exclusive lock by someone else?

Comment: Sorry here it is:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/updateExcel.py", line 13, in <module>
    wb.save("C:\\Todolist2.xlsx")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 367, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 282, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Todolist2.xlsx'

Comment: And here's the other error:  yes it does
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/updateExcel.py", line 8, in <module>
    modDate = os.stat("C:\\example.xlsx")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\example.xlsx'

Comment: Yes C:\example.xlsx and C:\Todolist2.xlsx does exist.  These files are not locked by anyone else because these files are local to my machine.  When I run it the first time, it works.  It opens Todolist2.  Just doesnt work thereafter.

Comment: First, edit the tracebacks into the question, don't try to cram them into comments.

Comment: Second, "local to my machine" doesn't mean not locked. On Windows, many programs—like Notepad and Excel—often lock files when opening them, meaning no other program has permission to write the file until they close it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two different problems here but they may be related.

Since you gave a traceback for the Permission Denied error on `C:\Todolist2.xlsx`, let's look at that one.

On Windows, many programs, when they open a file, put a lock on it. This is especially true for "applications" programs, like Excel and Notepad. If one program has a file locked, any another program that tries to open that file to overwrite it will get a permissions error.

And that's exactly what you're seeing: The first time through, your code overwrites `Todolist2.xslx`, then uses `startfile` to tell Excel (or some application that's registered for Excel files) to open it, which works. Then it tries to overwrite the same file, which Excel presumably still has locked and open, which fails.

Depending on what you're actually trying to do here, there are a few possible workarounds:

- Copy `Todolist2.xlsx` to a temporary file, then start that temporary.
- Create new files `Todolist2.xlsx`, `Todolist2-1.xlsx`, etc., and keep opening them.
- Use either COM automation or a GUI scripting framework like `autogui` to make Excel open a copy of the file rather than opening the file itself.
- Use either of the above to make Excel close the file before overwriting the file and launching it.
- Launch a new Excel instance to open the file using `subprocess.Popen`, so you can kill it and launch a new one.
- Rewrite your whole code to build the spreadsheet using Excel COM automation, rather than by building a file to pass to it.

Comment: Abarnert: do you mean to use keyboard/mouse simulation or hotkey simulation to close a worksheet that is already open?  or do you mean using subprocess to open an instance of the worksheet, that way I can continue to write to it while open and just keep closing and opening it?  I don't really See documentation on COM.   Autogui I understand but not COM.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @superx The fifth option is using `subprocess`. The third option is using something like `autogui` or COM automation. The other options are different options. And honestly, I think the first is probably simplest. As for COM automation—it's not actually called that anymore, but I don't know what it _is_ called. It also works through .NET interop instead of directly in most modern Windows software. But `pywin32.win32com` still works, if you read the old tutorials. (Or using Python.NET, or maybe IronPython, to talk .NET directly might be easier—much closer to the current VB.NET documentation…)

Comment: Thanks for throwing me the suggestions.  I will try to look up subprocess.  TBH, i just finished reading 'automate the boring stuff with python', and this is literally my first project.  I find most of the excel modules deal with reading/writing, parsing, but not much for opening up a read only copy of a excel file, and auto refreshing the entire sheet if someone made changes to it.  This is really my whole goal.  But thanks for throwing your suggestions my way, i will try to persevere.